# Up a Directory Script?

Tags: linux, scripting, cd

I've been trying to create a bash script that can move up a directory. I created this script, but when ran it does not execute anything. I tried adding a print statement to it, and that does work. Is there a certain way I should be executing this?
Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
DIR=$1
NUM=$PWD
for ((c=1; c <= DIR; c++))
do
    echo $NUM
    cd $NUM/..
done
```

Comment: Scripts run in a subprocess. Changes they make to the environment don't affect the calling shell.

Comment: Can you make it a [function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) rather than an executable script?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you like to move a directory up in the directory tree.

---

This is a script make aliases in .bashrc Like: `alias up1='cd../' alias up2='cd../../'` and so on, I limit the depth 9. If you Run it multiple times the script only crate the not existing entrys. May I will able to make it delete entry if you give less depth then script would manage this alias.

Not exactly you looking for but since script running in they own instance you cannot make them affect your current shell. Also after this script create aliases you need re authenticate or open a new shell, from that point they will work till you not delete the alias entry from .bashrc.

```
#!/bin/sh

[[ ! $# == 1 ]] && echo "Only one parameter accepted" && exit 1
[[ $( echo $1 | grep -c ^[1-9]$ ) -eq 0 ]] && echo "parameter must be between 1 and 9" && exit 1

cdcommand=""
for (( i = 1 ; i <= $1 ; i++ )); do
        cdcommand=$(echo $cdcommand | sed 's/^/\.\.\//g')
                [[ $( cat ~/.bashrc | grep -c "alias up$i='cd $cdcommand' ") == 0 ]] &&
                echo "alias up$i='cd $cdcommand' "  >> ~/.bashrc
done
```

Comment: Wait no, i'm making a script where i'll input "up 2" and it'll go up in directory so if i do "up 2" it'll move me from /blah/blah/yo to /blah/

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes :  Please edit your Q so people will see your requirement. As is someone has wasted their time writing this answer, and X people have wasted their time reading it and your comment. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.